# skipping an array when it is null

Tags: c#, arrays, null, skip, unity-game-engine

I have objects in my 2d game that are in an array list. These objects instantiate other objects in the game. Which ones that instantiate is based on random. However, these may be destroyed during gameplay. The code still tries to look for the destroyed Transform and so I told it to only instantiate from the array when it isn't null, fixing the error message. Still, the behavior remains. As one of these arrays spawns a gameObject every set number of seconds, it can still decide to spawn from an array that is null. When it randomly selects an array that is null, there is a time period where the play has to sit and wait for something to happen, which is of course unacceptable. How do I tell the game that when an array is null, to skip it and go to the next one, in order to get rid of that waiting period in the game? I also am aware that void doesn't return anything. It's just a placeholder at the end of the script because I can't type in break or continue since it's not a for loop. I posted this before and once the error message left I thought that was the end of it. So sorry for posting it a second time. Thanks in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


public class podControl : MonoBehaviour {


public Transform [] spawns;
public float spawnTime = 6f;
public float secondSpawnTime = 3f;      
public GameObject podPrefab;



void Start ()
{

    InvokeRepeating ("landingPod", spawnTime, secondSpawnTime);

}



void landingPod ()
{

    int spawnIndex = Random.Range (0, spawns.Length);

    if (spawns[spawnIndex] != null) {

        Instantiate (podPrefab, spawns [spawnIndex].position, spawns [spawnIndex].rotation); 

    }
    else {
        if (spawns [spawnIndex] = null)
            return;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply keep looking for a valid spawn before you `Instantiate` it :

```
void landingPod()
{

    int spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawns.Length);

    while(spawns[spawnIndex] == null)
    {
        spawnIndex = Random.Range(0, spawns.Length);
    }

    Instantiate(podPrefab, spawns[spawnIndex].position, spawns[spawnIndex].rotation);

}
```

And you had this where you do your return :

```
if (spawns[spawnIndex] = null)
```

By just having `=` and not `==` you're not verifying if its null but giving this `spawns[spawnIndex]` the null value.

Comment: There we go it works now. I didn't know you could apply == to a null so it never even occurred to me. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome and yes the same way you verified if it wasn't null by doing `!=` you can use `==` to do the opposite. @JoeClark

Comment: @JoeClark if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: of course I'd be more than happy to. Thanks for showing me the ropes lol

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting array positions to null, fill them with the last item and keep track of the items count in the array.

```
public Transform [] spawns;
private int spawnsCount;

// Index must be in the range [0 ... spawnsCount - 1] and spawnsCount > 0.
public DeleteSpawnAt(int index)
{
    spawnsCount--;
    spawns[index] = spawns[spawnsCount];
    spawns[spawnsCount] = null;
}
```

In the range 0 to spawnsCount - 1 you will always have non null transforms. All the `null` entries will be at the end of the array.

And then create a an index with

```
int spawnIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnsCount);
```

---

Delete "D":

```
              +-----------------------+
              |                       |
              V                       |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                                    |<--|
                                    spawnCount--
```

after:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | J | E | F | G | H | I |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```